# Force program to treat symlinks as real files using LD_PRELOAD

Tags: symlink, ld-preload, zpaq

GOAL: I want to force zpaq into backing up symlinks as though they were real files, possibly by fooling it (using LD_PRELOAD or some sort or FUSE system) into thinking symlinks are actual files.

I want to create/find a library that forces programs to read symlinks
as they were actual files, and then use LD_PRELOAD (or something
similar) to run the program in that environment.

In other words, when the program calls readdir() [or whatever], the
symlink appears as an actual file, and when the program calls open()
[or whatever], it opens the actual target file, not the symlink.

Is there any way to do this? The otherwise wonderful zpaq doesn't
support symlinks at the moment, and the files are on different drives,
so I can't use hard linking either.

Comment: FWIW, a better way to do this would be to talk to Matt about adding a flag to ZPAQ to follow symlinks; I doubt he would have a problem with it, especially if you're willing to contribute a patch.  If he isn't willing, ZPAQ is open-source; you can always create a modified version.

Comment: Thanks. I actually have contacted Matt about this (and several other zpaq suggestions), and Matt has been great in acknowledging my suggestions, although, of course, he can't implement them all immediately. I'm a little scared to modify the code myself, and, more importantly, I think fooling programs into thinking symlinks are actual files would be useful in general, not just for zpaq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what is the problem?  You seem to know about LD_PRELOAD already; all you need to do is write a library which exposes the correct functions and put it in LD_PRELOAD.  [This link](https://rafalcieslak.wordpress.com/2013/04/02/dynamic-linker-tricks-using-ld_preload-to-cheat-inject-features-and-investigate-programs/) explains the process a bit more verbosely if you need it.

The only potential issue is that calls to things in glibc don't always get linked to the symbols you might expect… for example, a call to write may actually call `__write` (if it doesn't get inlined to something even lower-level).  Depending on your optimization level, some functions calls will actually be removed completely, such as memset with a fixed length.  There are also checked variants for many functions if you're using `_FORTIFY_SOURCE`.  I don't *think* this should be an issue for readlink, but you're probably just going to have to TIAS.

Basically, just do it.  If it doesn't work, *then* come back to SO if you need help debugging.

Comment: TIAS? try it and see?

Comment: Yes, TIAS = try it and see.